# How to install ZeroMQ library on Windows 10 for Java?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, zeromq

I want to use ZeroMQ for Windows 10 64bit to use in Java.

I am using Intelj as my IDE.
I googled and the only thing I found out was to compile library from source ( Mostly for Linux ).

Is there any way to use a compiled ZeroMQ library, so I can import it easily in my java code?

Comment: I would use maven. https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.zeromq%7Cjeromq%7C0.4.3%7Cjar

Comment: Have a look at this link as well describing pros and cons of ZeroMQ and available alternatives. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052358/understanding-zeromq-java-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use zeromq in java you have 2 choices, 1. Use [jeromq](http://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) which is a java implementation of zeromq, and 2. Use jzmq which is a jni binding required libzmq installed on your system.
If you are willing to use jzmq you can download and install libzmq from [here](http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows)

Comment: Thank you, i guess that's the best way then.

Comment: jeromq have some limitation as given on there page. I have downloaded and installed http://zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows 4.0.4

Now What's the next step i am not able to go beyond it

Comment: Now you can download and use both jeromq and jzmq in your project

Comment: what i have zmq.jar referenced in my java project. I am getting error Getting error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path in IntelliJ ide with windows 10

Comment: Same, using the jar but still getting the 'no jzmq in java.library.path' error.